# How to show a loading image mean while a submit form is being executed in Sitecore 9 Forms

Tags: sitecore-forms, javascript

Currently I have a form (created using Sitecore 9 Forms not with WFFM module) and on submit (custom submit action button). While clicking submit button, I have to show the loading image in the client side whenever a Background server operation is in progress.

How can I do this with Sitecore 9 Forms?

Answer (score 4):

You can add some javascript on your webpage to listen on your submit button and show a loader icon.

To have some handles, you can add custom css classes on your submit buttons.

This can be done, either by adding them by the contenteditor.

[image]

Or you could also edit the Website\Views\FormBuilder\FieldTemplates\button.cshtml file to make it hardcoded.

```
$(".showLoader").click(showLoader());
```

Note that you can add css-classes on almost all components of the Sitecore Forms feature.

Comment: Is it possible to show success message in same page (not move to next page(thank you page). currently i'm using sitecore form with submit action button. while submit the button, i want to show the success message for above or below submit button. Is there any option to show this message

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I faced the same issue working on Sitecore 9.1.1 with Sitecore Forms. (This is how I landed here actually).

Sitecore Forms uses jQuery Ajax Unobtrusive, which uses some data attributes to handle different Forms actions. You can know more about this here https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/unobtrusive-ajax

The one I'm interested in is "data-ajax-begin" which Gets or sets the name of the JavaScript function to call immediately before the page is updated.

So the idea is to define a function that does the animation in that data attribute.

Sitecore uses InitializeAjaxOptions pipeline to initialize these data attributes.

```
public class InitializeAjaxOptions : MvcPipelineProcessor<RenderFormEventArgs>
{
    private readonly IFormRenderingContext _formRenderingContext;

    public InitializeAjaxOptions(IFormRenderingContext formRenderingContext)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) formRenderingContext, nameof (formRenderingContext));
  this._formRenderingContext = formRenderingContext;
        }

    public override void Process(RenderFormEventArgs args)
        {
             Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) args, nameof (args));
             if (!args.ViewModel.IsAjax)
                return;
             if (args.HtmlHelper.ViewContext.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled)
                 {
                     IDictionary<string, object> unobtrusiveHtmlAttributes = new AjaxOptions()
    {
      HttpMethod = "Post",
      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.ReplaceWith,
      UpdateTargetId = args.FormHtmlId,
      OnSuccess = FormattableString.Invariant(FormattableStringFactory.Create("$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#{0}');$.fxbFormTracker.parse('#{1}');", (object) args.FormHtmlId, (object) args.FormHtmlId))
    }.ToUnobtrusiveHtmlAttributes();
    foreach (string key in (IEnumerable<string>) unobtrusiveHtmlAttributes.Keys)
      args.Attributes[key] = unobtrusiveHtmlAttributes[key];
  }
  if (!args.IsPost)
  {
    args.QueryString.Add("fxb.FormItemId", (object) args.ViewModel.ItemId.ToGuid());
    args.QueryString.Add("fxb.HtmlPrefix", (object) this._formRenderingContext.Prefix.Trim('.'));
  }
  args.RouteName = "FormBuilder";
}
}
```

So I created a new pipeline to replace it, which would add the data attributes I need.
I added this line (OnBegin = “OnBegin”) which will add the data-ajax-begin attribute to all forms, with the value “OnBegin” which is the JavaScript function I’ll need to write.

The JavaScript function is very simple I’ll just select all buttons with a specific class, and add another class.

```
 OnBegin = function (xhr) {            
        $(".loader-button").addClass("loader");
    }
```

With help of a Front End developer, I added the CSS rules that will create the animation when the user submits the form.

Of course, don’t forget to add the patch configuration file for the new pipeline.

```
<forms.renderForm>      
    <processor type="Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Pipelines.RenderForm.InitializeAjaxOptions, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc">
      <patch:attribute name="type">ProjectX.Feature.Forms.Pipelines.RenderForm.InitializeAjaxOptions, ProjectX.Feature.Forms</patch:attribute>
    </processor>
  </forms.renderForm>
```

That’s it, and it worked as expected.

[image]

Here is the full blog I wrote about it as well.
http://jaffal.me/show-progress-indicator-while-submitting-sitecore-form/